# How to read Date in 'Aug 02, 2021' format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Date stored in DB in format: `'02/08/2021'` (Date selected from mobile app). I want it to be stored/returned in format: `Aug 02, 2021`.

This is what I have tried:

```
declare @value Date = '02/08/2021'
select Convert(varchar(30), @value, 107)
```

But, I get error saying:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

How can I fix this using SQL Query?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do the formatting *in the database*? That feels much more like a client concern than a database one. (I'd also recommend that you don't store it in the database as text at all, but as a DATE column. The database should generally represent the underlying data, rather than any particular presentation of that data.)

Comment: If you declare your date properly (`declare @value Date = '20210725'`), it works as expected

Comment: This statement (`declare @value Date = '02/08/2021'` )is the reason for the error. Use unambiguous date format `declare @value Date = '20210802'`

Comment: @JonSkeet,@HoneyBadger,@Zhorov : The format which stores in DB is fetched from mobile app. Is there any way that I can convert it using SQL ??

Comment: If the dates are stored as text in this format (`dd/mm/yyyy`), this will help: `declare @value Date = CONVERT(date, '02/08/2021', 103)`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger : The declared date is supposed to be in 02/08/2021 format. Is there any way that i can convert using select Convert(varchar(30),@value,107) statement??

Comment: Again, it would be better to do this *in the app*. (That would make it easier to localize for different users, etc.) Leave the database storing data, and the app presenting the data. (This will also make it a lot easier to change databases in the future if you need to, and accommodate other requirement changes.)

Comment: @Zhorov : I tried that, But it didnot return me Aug 02, 2021 in this format.

Comment: @Philip, of course, you need both statements: `declare @value date = CONVERT(date, '02/08/2021', 103); select Convert(varchar(30), @value, 107);`.

Comment: @Zhorov : How do I put this query in my SP??                                                                   My SP line is: CASE WHEN CPN.ValueType='Date'  THEN  CONVERT(date, CPI.value, 103) Select Convert(varchar(30), CPI.value , 107) ELSE                                                               I am getting error:                                                                                                                                 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetChecklistQuestionWithAnswer, 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: String to date an back to string `Convert(varchar(30), Convert(date,  CPI.value, 103) , 107)`

Comment: *"I have Date stored in DB in format"* - Let me stop you right there. [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may convert string first

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(50) = '02/08/2021'
declare @value Date = SUBSTRING(@s,4,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@s,1,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@s,7,4)
select Convert(varchar(30), @value, 107)
```